# Compute sums of variances

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

I am trying to compute $VAR(2X-3Y)$ which may be rewritten as $$E\left((2X-3Y)^2\right) - \left(E(2X-3Y)\right)^2=E(4X^2-6XY +9Y^2) - E(2X -3Y)E(2X-3Y)$$

How do I compute the rest?

Comment: The variables X and Y are not independent...

Comment: Do you know linearity of expectation, i.e. $E(aX+bY)=aE(X)+b(Y)$ whenever expectations exist?

Comment: Typo: the above should read $bE(Y)$ instead of $b(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the results in this link: http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~cslui/ERG2040C/tutorial11_notes.pdf
about the expectation of **linear** combinations of variables. It will help you **simplify** the expression you have got. After that, you will have to use the definition of expectation, **depending on** what is the probability **distribution** of your variables.